# Reminder recurring events

Tags: mysql

I have a problem, my query isn't working properly

`SELECT * FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b on a.eid = b.id 
LEFT JOIN c ON a.cid = c.id 
WHERE 
DAYOFYEAR(a.start) BETWEEN :startdate_day_of_year AND :enddate_day_of_year 
AND
:year BETWEEN a.start AND a.end`

:startdate_day_of_year and :enddate_day_of_year are passed from the user input... 1-365
:year is passed from the user input...2011

The problem is that an event can recur every year (ie: event started in 2008 and goes through 2012). It has to display the event every year...

When I've added table c to the mix i started getting limited results... if i replaced the where part with the fixed dates instead of dayofyear and year it started working the way it should... but then i cannot get the recurring events.

Thannk you!
BR

Answer (score 0):

Recurring events are rather different from non-recurring events. If recurring events had e.g. year of beginning and year of end, I'd have a separate table for recurring events.

Else, I'd have a Boolean column `is_yearly_event` and would only check year if it is not set:
`...AND (a.is_yearly_event != 0 OR :year BETWEEN a.start AND a.end)`

Comment: Well, how do you tell recurring events from one-time events then?